# Disable swipe to refresh in chrome CustomTab

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I'm using chrome `CustomTab` to open a url inside my app, using `customTabsIntent.launchUrl` method and `CustomTabsIntent.Builder`. Here's how I'm doing it right now:

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(someUrl);
```

is there any way to disable the swipetorefresh behaviour that is set by default, in the `CustomTab`? by modifying the builder or something? (without making any changes to the website)

Answer (score 1):

No, This is not currently possible, as Custom Tabs will respect the behaviour of the opened web page. If changing the page is possible, [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior) can help